# call the another function within a function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In laravel I want to call a function within function to make recursive.I caught the route error.how to call the function 'recursive in tableFetch'

```
class queryTest extends Controller
{
 public function tableFetch() {
   recursive();
 }
 function recursive(){
   //condition
 }
}
```

I want to do it for check the manager of the given person and then get the manager of the fetched value in query so need to do it recursive

Comment: It is not a good idea to call a controller method inside another, instead, you can use a redirect. Could you please explain why you need to do this?

Comment: Could you use `$this->recursive()` to call a function in same class

Answer (score 1):

A controller is not a good place for this. Instead, manage it in your Person Model(or whatever you have).

Everyone has a manager. So, your model has HasOne relation to itself.

Person Model:

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'manager_id');
}
```

Now if you need to check the manager of given person untill you meet a certain condition you can do it inside the model and get the result in the controller.

```
public function checkManager()
{
    $manager = $this->manager

    if (check manager)
        return $manager;

    //check for the last manager
    return $this->manager ? $this->checkManager() : null;
}
```

Inside controller

```
function index()
{
    $person = Person::find($id);

    $manager = $person->checkManager();// this will do the recursive you need
}
```

Comment: what does  $person = Person::find($id); returns

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
class queryTest extends Controller
{
  public function tableFetch() {
     $this->recursive();
}
  function recursive(){
    //condition
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask more precise details about your needs, because Laravel has some complications.
try doing this :

```
class queryTest extends Controller
{
     public function tableFetch() {
         $this->recursive();
     }
     public function recursive() {
         //condition
     }
}
```